# How do you combine underlining a character and adding a hat accent to the same character in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to write some math notation in Rmarkdown and can't figure out how to underline and hat a single character.

For example, I can achieve the hat accent:

```
$\hat{e}$
```

and the underline:

```
$\underline{e}$
```

but how do I combine the two notations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple matter of combining the two calls:

`$\hat{\underline{e}}$`

gives

[image: underlinedhatted e]